# Measurable functions, $\sigma$-Algebra.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega=\Bbb R$ and $\mathscr A:=\{\;[a,b]\bigcap \Bbb Q \;\mid\; a\leqslant b,\quad a,b \in \Bbb Q\}$

What is the $\sigma$-Algebra generated by $\mathscr A$ in $\Bbb R$ and which functions $f: \Bbb R \to[-\infty, \infty]$ are $\sigma(\mathscr A)$-measurable ?

---

Isn't $\mathscr A$ a Trace-$\sigma$-Algebra, so isn't it it's own $\sigma$-Algebra?

All functions that are constant on $[a,b]\bigcap \Bbb Q$ are $\sigma(\mathscr A)$-measurable right?

Comment: for easiest way, you can use color technique.

Comment: @hellzone : What does "color technique" mean?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan It means copy your homework from someone else :)

Comment: @hellzone : A) That is a rather absurd thing to say on a forum such as this. B) I still don't understand what that has to do with colouring.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is correct, but the conclusion is a little scary, so not sure :

Note that singleton sets are in $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ (since $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is closed under countable intersections) and hence $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$, the power set of $\mathbb{Q}$ (since it is closed under countable unions).

Thus, a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to [-\infty, +\infty]$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}(U)\subset \mathbb{Q}$ for all $U \subset [-\infty, +\infty]$ open. But for any $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$, $x \in f^{-1}([-\infty, +\infty])$, so there are no measurable functions.